# Corresponding rules in MacOS for this Iptables rules

Tags: macos, vmware, iptables

I need to give Internet access to a VM under Vmware fusion 7 in Host-Only mode. I know how to do it in Linux, with the following IPtables rules:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i vboxnet0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

But I can not find out how to do it in MacOS Sierra. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably belongs on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is also posted there, but no one answers me. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265237/corresponding-ipfw-rules-in-macos-for-this-iptables-rules

Comment: The way you formulate it with code for iptables, makes that only those who fully know and iptables, and pf and macos can answer. You're limiting the population of those that can give you a detailed answer by not including a clear and simple text version of what you want the ruleset to do. Also adding in Vmware doesn't make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in apple.stackexchange.com and here is the solution:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265237/corresponding-ipfw-rules-in-macos-for-this-iptables-rules/265298#265298

Answer (score 0):

You should look into configuring pf (packet filter) in macos (or OS X) it's been included since Lion.

It Is substantially different from what you're used to, so there will be a learning curve.

pf originates on OpenBSD. They have information that includes examples on how to write pf rules.

https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/config.html#config

Using it for NAT has it's own manual:
https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/nat.html

To get started on the mac: 
http://krypted.com/mac-security/a-cheat-sheet-for-using-pf-in-os-x-lion-and-up/ it's a bit old, but still should you get started.

I've no idea how vmware fusion does networking on the mac (parallels tends to add a ton of interfaces you see on the mac), I'd start with simple examples and slowly grow to a more complex setup.

Comment: I do not know how to wirite this rules nor how to configure PF, thats the reason I came here asking for help.